# Analytical equation for time to empty a pressurized water tank

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

I need help determining an equation for time to empty a pressurized tank. I have a sealed water tank pressurized with nitrogen, where the cross-sectional area of the water inside the tank is [image: Area] and the outlet area is [image: Area3].
[image]
The height of the water is given by $h$, and the height of the container is given by $H$. After the valve is suddenly opened, I am looking to derive an analytical equation for the time to empty the tank. Since the pressure is quite high, I cannot assume the velocity of the water in the tank is zero as it is being emptied.
I am using a combination of Modified Bernoulli's equation and continuity to derive a formula for the change in height of the water over time, then attempting to integrate.

Here is my work so far:

From Modified Bernoulli's equation...

[image: Mod Bernoulli]

the height $h_1$ is just $h$ and is a function of time. $P_2$ is zero (gauge pressure), and $v_1$ should not be assumed to be zero, as the tank empties rather quickly. $h_L$ is given by:

[image: Darcy weisbach].

(where $k$ is the total loss coefficient) From continuity quation we can express $v_1$ in terms of $v_2$ :

[image: continuity]

The pressure $P_1$ can be expressed as a function of $h$:

[image: pressure]

Combining and solving for exit velocity yields:

[image: exit velocity]

Since the exit velocity must be equal to:

[image: v2]

Thus we can express the system as the following diff eq:

[image: diffeq]

**I am unsure if I have derived everything correctly, so please call me out on any mistakes!**

This is where I get stuck. In order to solve for time, the equation becomes too difficult for me:

[image: time]

I have tried simplifying the equation in terms of constants and $h$ but even wolfram alpha could not give me a solution